# Choosing fast crypto for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

`AES` seems like a relatively quick way to do strong encryption and there are clearly native .NET crypto service providers.  What mode(s) are best?  Will something like `ECB` provide me with a speed advantage over other modes?

Comment: There's no generic answer to that question. It depends very much on the specifics of your use case. A strong and fast cryptographic algorithm doesn't automatically give you a strong and fast end to end cryptosystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use ECB.  Electronic code book encrypts blocks independent of each other.  Use something like CBC which generates IV for subsequent blocks based upon the ciphertext for the current block.  It's far less susceptible to cryptanalysis.

There is no possible speed advantage worth that...and if there is a speed advantage (citation?) of ECB over CBC it's most certainly negligible.

Comment: And CBC only needs very little effort for performing the XOR operation for linking the blocks - definitely worth the few extra CPU cycles. I assume if you compare ECB and CBC the difference will be smaller than the measure tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at ThreeFish as an alternative to AES/Rijndael

http://www.schneier.com/threefish.html

There a C# implementation of Threefish and Skein (secure hash algorithm) at http://code.google.com/p/skeinfish/

Comment: There's no reason to recommend anything other than AES for production. It's undergone the most analysis of any other modern cipher, and is the only public block cipher currently supported by NIST and the NSA's Suite B. It's also unlikely that its performance will be prohibitive for the OP.